# Removing Rows and Columns in .dat file using python

Tags: python, linux

I'm wondering if there's a simple method for deleting particular rows and columns in python. Apologies if this is a trivial question.

To give some context, I'm currently writing a script to automate a series of linux commands(specifically ciao Chandra telescope analysis commands), part of which saves the output of a certain command to a .dat file. At present the output has included some rows and columns which I don't want in there...

E.G the data currently looks like:

Data for Table Block HISTOGRAM

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROW    CELL   RCENTRE              RHALFWIDTH           AREA                 COUNTS               SUR_BRI             

     1      1          1.016260150          1.016260150        12.9783552105                    0                    0
     2      1          3.048780450          1.016260150        38.9350656315                  1.0     0.02568378873336
     3      1          5.081300750          1.016260150        64.8917760526                  1.0     0.01541027324001
     4      1          7.113821050          1.016260150        90.8484864736                  1.0     0.01100733802858
     5      1          9.146341350          1.016260150       116.8051968946                    0                    0
     6      1   

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
```

I want to remove the first few rows which incorporate the "Data for Table Block Histogram" and dashes, and also the first two columns which begin with "ROW" and "CELL"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your separator is tabulation or that you don't need the exact same distance between columns at the end, and assuming the interesting lines begin with a number (as shown in your example) you could write something like that:

```
def cutFile(fname, firstWantedColumn):
    """Keep wanted lines and colums: detect lines beginning with number and keep input columns"""
    f=open(fname, "r")
    lf = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    txtOut = ""
    for l in lf:
        if l[0].isdigit(): #detect if first char is a number
            txtOut += "\t".join(l.split()[firstWantedColumn:]) + "\n"
    g = open(".".join(fname.split(".")[:-1]) + "_cutted" + fname.split(".")[-1])
    g.write(txtOut)
    g.close()

cutFile("myFile.dat", 2)
```

Edit: this is a bruteforce solution, maybe you were talking about an advanced and oneliner solution but I'm not sur this exists.